# JavaScript: Using await to make asnyc code look more synchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to understand the asnyc await functionality.
Therefore, i want to use an asnyc function, resolve it and do the following logs *sequentially afterwards*.

How do I achieve this? Or am I  understanding something fundamentally wrong?

```
const test = async function() {
    console.log('hi 1');
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('timout1')
    }, 1000);
    console.log('hi 2');
    console.log('hi 3');
}
test()
```

**Result**

```
hi 1
hi 2
hi 3
timout1
```

**Expected Result**

```
hi 1
timout1
hi 2
hi 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await` for promises only and the `setTimeout` function doesn't return a Promise. However you can await a Promise that is resolved using `setTimeout` like so which will give you the desired result.

So, the function execution will halt untill either the Promise being `await`ed gets resolved or gets rejected and then continue.

```js
const test = async function() {
  console.log('hi 1');
         // return a new promise resolved after setTimeout callback is fired
  await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timout1')
      resolve()
    }, 1000)
  }))
  console.log('hi 2');
  console.log('hi 3');
}

test()
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Ah! You are right! Just because *setTimeout()* is asnyc doesn´t mean its a promise!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code help you to understand async await.

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('resolved');
     }, 2000);
   });
}

async function asyncCall() {
   console.log('hi 1');
   const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
   console.log(result);
   console.log('hi 2');
   console.log('hi 3');
}

asyncCall();
```